# HP 3520 has stopped working. Which print service does eOS use?

Tags: printer

I have used my Deskjet 3520 printer on Elementary OS in the past - I don't print frequently so the OS will have had update patches applied (0.4.1 Loki).

I have the printer connected via USB to remove wifi from the equation. The printer is functional from another PC, I've tried rebooting, removing and re-adding the printer.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following resolved it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip --reinstall
```

I also removed and re-added the printer in System Settings. When selecting the driver via the add printer wizard, ts easy to miss that the right hand driver pane is scrollable so I think I may have previously been selecting the incorrect driver. There is a driver for the 3520 series further down the list